# Find the range of $f \colon \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, $f(x) = 2x^3 + 3x^2 − 4$. Is $f$ injective? Is $f$ surjective?

Tags: functions, polynomials

> A function $f \colon \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is defined by $f(x) = 2x^3 + 3x^2 − 4$.
>
> Find the range of $f$. Is $f$ one–to–one (injective)? Is $f$ onto (surjective)? Is $f$ a bijection? Give reasons for all your answers.

I recently attempted to solve a problem of this type, but was completely unsure of what to do. The only thing I remember is that one or more of these properties could be checked by taking either the first or second derivatives (again, can't remember).

I would greatly appreciate it if people could please take the time to explain how one would go about solving this type of problem.

Comment: A good idea should be to first try to plot the graph that at least would give you an intuitive idea concerning its injectivity and surjectivity.

Comment: You've been around awhile, so it should be clear that you should fill in some of the context around your own efforts to solve this.  What are the first and second derivatives?  What properties do you see that these have?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have that f(x) is continuos and

- $\lim_{x\to \infty} f(x)=\infty$
- $\lim_{x\to -\infty} f(x)=-\infty$

therefore by IVT $f(x)$ is surjective.

Note also that

$$f'(x)=6x^2+6x=6x(x+1) \quad f''(x)=12x+6$$

therefore $x=0$ is a local minimum and $x=-1$ is  alocal maximum, thus $f(x)$ is not injective.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What about the range? How does one ascertain this?

Comment: @ThePointer Since $f(x)$ is surjective the range is $\mathbb{R}$. To ascertain that we suffice continuity and the limits at $\pm \infty$ to conclude by IVT that all real values are reached by$ f(x)$.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

- A third degree polynomial function is always **surjective** (onto $\mathbb{R}$) because:
  $$\lim_{x\to\pm\infty}\left(ax^3+bx^2+cx+d\right)=\pm\infty \quad\quad(a > 0)$$
  or
  $$\lim_{x\to\pm\infty}\left(ax^3+bx^2+cx+d\right)=\mp\infty \quad\quad(a < 0)$$
  and polynomials are *continuous*. Your $f(x)$ is such a polynomial, hence the range is $\mathbb{R}$.
- It is only **injective** if it is *monotonic*, i.e. if the derivative has a constant sign. 
  In your case the derivative is $f'(x)=6x(x+1)$ so it does not have a constant sign and therefore $f$ is not monotonic, hence not injective.
- A function is **bijective** if (and only if) it is injective and surjective, so yours is not.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure you necessarily need to go to the derivatives.  Consider the following:

"Injective" - does it take the same value for different inputs?  If so, it's not injective; if not, it is.

"Surjective" - since it's defined as a function from the reals onto the reals, does it reach every real?  If so, it's surjective, if not, not.

Of course, it's bijective iff it's both injective and surjective.

Hint: an odd polynomial from the reals onto the reals will always be surjective.

Answer (score 1):

We have that f(x) is continuos and

limx→∞f(x)=∞
limx→−∞f(x)=−∞
therefore by IVT f(x) is surjective.

Note also that

f′(x)=6x2+6x=6x(x+1)f′′(x)=12x+6
therefore x=0 is a local minimum and x=−1 is alocal maximum, thus f(x) is not injective.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).